# How do I get growl for windows to use native windows 8/10 notifications?

Tags: growl

I'm using gntp-send to send messages to a [growl for windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/) instance. GFW hasn't been maintained a while so there dosen't seem to be support for windows 10 style notifications. How would I get GFW to work with the new style notifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an alternative implementation along the same vein of Jonno's one: https://github.com/BobVul/GrowlToToast/blob/master/README.md

The basic principle is the same, but this also sends the original title as sent by the Growl source, and supports a 'silent mode' that stops the Windows 10 notification sound.

### Installation

See the [Installation instructions in the README](https://github.com/BobVul/GrowlToToast/blob/master/README.md). This has changed across different versions.

Answer (score 2):

I had put together a quick display to mimic this, literally just using the SDK and a quick hack up of the Windows 10 Notification system. Unfortunately notifications require a higher version of the .NET framework than Growl uses (Displays are build for 2.0), so it requires a helper exe which simply takes one argument, the description for the notification.

Source and EXE are available here if you wanted to use it or it can help anyone:

https://github.com/Jonno12345/GrowlForWindows10/releases

Quick video of it in action:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its terribly hacky and there's three different things I need to pull in.

Firstly I need a way to actually generate the new style notifications. I'm using [toaster](https://github.com/nels-o/toaster) for this, download and unzip this somewhere appropriate.

Next you need something to glue toaster and growl together - I used [scripty](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/displays/scripty) for this. Scripty is not really documented - Basically, you can retrieve the information from growl as command.exe variables and I did a lot of poking around with 'echo' to work out what worked.

```
@echo off
set arg1=%2
shift 
shift
shift
set arg2=%~7

C:\Users\geek\AppData\Local\Growl\2.0.0.0\Displays\Scripty\toast\toast.exe -t %arg1% -m "%arg2% " -w
```

I've put toast in the scripty folder since it seems appropriate and invoked it with a batch file

Basically it pulls out the title and message contents (title is %2 and message is %10 - which needs the use of the shift command).

This will fire up a windows 10 native notification as needed. You could also add a locally hosted image on the notification but I'll leave that as an exercise to the user. It also seems to fire up a cmd window, which needs to be fixed, but another toaster notification app may do the trick

Comment: I actually made something *slightly* less hacky than this (native display that sends to a "notification" program, unfortunately it seems to only allow .NET2.0 displays and the notification needs 4.5 I believe), although it's by no means production quality, I literally just used the SDK they provide and haven't really even renamed anything ... Can stick the files on my Github if you wanted it though. Made a quick video if you cared ;) http://i.imgur.com/ncrxWzE.gif

Comment: I'd be happy to give it a try. I was ridiculously tired when I threw this together and someone suggested calling toast from a c# app as an alternative. I'm suprised no one's done this. There's at least two options for creating toaster notifications and a few requests. I guess GFW's sorta dead, but I can't really find anything else that lets me send notifications as easily between my linux and windows boxen

Comment: You can call a VBScript from Growl Scripty, and if Wscript.exe is the default script engine, there will be no console window.