# How can I send a notification to a Windows 10 computer from the command line

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, notifications

I'd like to create/send native Windows notifications from the command-line as part of a few automated tasks that I have set up, both on my local machine and for similar tasks on my home server. Both computers run Windows 10, and are on the same network.

I'm looking to receive the notifications from **both** computers in the action centre on my main computer.

Is there a command-line tool I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: There might be a better way, but one way would be to use [Growl](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/) with [a plugin](https://superuser.com/questions/1039396/how-do-i-get-growl-for-windows-to-use-native-windows-8-10-notifications) that can display them as native notifications/toasts. (Growl can accept notification commands from the command line.)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751857/scriptable-way-to-add-notification-to-action-center) link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 19/05/2018:**

[Pullover](https://github.com/cgrossde/Pullover) can no longer create native Windows notifications as of version 
1.3.0 (due to fixes to support the Fall Creators Update), so this is now only a partial answer to the question. It's still a viable way to get notifications from/via [Pushover](https://pushover.net/), but they won't be native.

---

Something I've been using for a while for mobile notifications is [Pushover](https://pushover.net/), which accepts notifications via an HTTP request and sends them to all (or a selection of) devices registered to your account. I've been using [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) to generate and send the necessary HTTP requests. (I know, not very 'Windows'y).

Yesterday I found out Pushover now has official desktop support for its notifications via the browser, and third third-party support from via a desktop client called [Pullover](https://github.com/cgrossde/Pullover) which displays any notifications received from Pushover as native Windows notifications. *Note that receiving desktop notifications requires a [license](https://pushover.net/clients/desktop).*

Here are the steps required to send a notification via [curl](https://github.com/cgrossde/Pullover):

1. [Register](https://pushover.net/login) for an account and log in
2. Download and install [Pullover](https://github.com/cgrossde/Pullover)
3. Login to Pullover and give your computer a device name
4. You should receive a "Welcome to Pushover!" notification confirming that notifications are working
5. Note down your **User Key** displayed on your account page
6. Scroll down, and click [Register an Application/Create an API Token](https://pushover.net/apps/build)
7. Enter a `Name`, and select `Script` as the `Type`
8. Accept the T&Cs, and click `Create Application`
9. Note down the **API Token/Key** you are given
10. Download [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) and stick it somewhere in your `%PATH%`
11. Open a Command Prompt
12. Enter

    ```
    curl --form-string "token=api-token" --form-string "user=user-token" --form-string "message=notification-text" --form-string "title=notification-title" https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json
    ```

    where `user-token` and `api-token` are the **User Key** and **API Token/Key** you recorded earlier, `notification-title` is the title of the notification and `notification-text` is the text
13. You should receive a notification with the title and text you just entered

Things to note:

- Other supported methods for generating notifications include emailing an account specific email address and web services such as [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/)
- Pushover allows 7,500 messages to be sent per application per month for free
- A maximum of ten devices can be linked to a single user account
- Device/computer names must be unique, or they will replace an existing device
- Internet access is required to send/receive notifications, although you will get any notifications which have been sent but not received when internet connectivity is restored (in my experience)

Comment: Firefox browser notifications can be turned into native notifications via the [GNotifer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/gnotifier/) extension - I don't know how Chrome's notifications display as it's not my primary browser

Answer (score 13):

If you want to create a native windows notification (a popup in bottom-right corner and persistant in notification center), you could take the following Powershell snippet as a template.

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47123275/1043209

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon

$objNotifyIcon.Icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "Info" 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "wzzup this is a title." 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "WHATS UPPP THIS IS A PARAGRAPH!"
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True

$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
Start-Sleep 500
```

It looks like this in notification center.

[image: demo]

Comment: You've reversed your text & title! :D

Comment: FYI for others trying this method, if you are trying to test notifications on a corporate PC with this approach, your company may have notification policies in place preventing this method from working. I just tested it on two of my work PCs, both running Windows 10 Enterprise and it did not work on either. Then I tried it on my personal PC with running Win 10 Pro with the exact same version, build, and Experience Pack numbers, and it worked fine there.

Comment: Why do you sleep 500 seconds, when in the line above you can control for how long the message is shown?

Comment: @Marduk When the process showing the notification exits, the notification popup will disappear instantly from desktop.

Answer (score 12):

Another way is the built in MSG.exe command that has been there since Vista. From a command prompt there the following:

msg /server:poseidon daniel "Please contact help desk immediately!"

Server is the name of computer you are sending the message to and daniel is a valid user name of the person using that computer. Fast and simple without any extra downloads.

Comment: Not available anymore in Windows 10.

Comment: works on my Windows 10 machines - you may have to make a small registry change but the command and it's use is definitely available in Windows 10

Comment: @TomGarrisi Why would you say all of that and not provide an explanation as to what registry change?

Comment: I believe it is this: Open `regedit` and go here "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Control \ Terminal Server", then set `AllowRemoteRPC` to 1 (src: https://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/msg-command/).

Comment: @JamesWilkins note that this also enables all remote access to your computer

Comment: @OrangeDog People can't just connect on a whim. They have to have security rights to connect. AllowRemoteRPC allows for the admin on the server to work with Remote Desktop Services.  Its most likely enabled by default on windows servers because about 90% of the time you'll be connecting remotely to your server to use and configure it.  Enabling the option only opens ports, simple as that, which can easily be firewalled to keep access within internal networks only. If everyone's an admin, then that may be a different story (if one gets infected or "hacked") lol.

Comment: If anyone needs the port reference it can be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc738291(v=ws.10)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Growl for Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/) for this. You'd need [growlnotify](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/help/growlnotify.aspx) to send the message and the full application where you receive the notification. As per the comments you will need a [plugin](https://superuser.com/q/1039396/10165) for native toast notifications.

On the receiving end, you will also need to enable notifications from other PCs and to set up a password.

[image]

We're assuming the system where the full GFW package is installed is 192.168.1.110.

On the sending end `growlnotify.com /r:"test1" /a:"test1" /host:192.168.1.110 /pass:test boo` registers the application. You need to do this *once* I prefer the batch varient here cause it has more useful warnings for initial setup. You can switch to the exe file once you know things work.

and something like `growlnotify.com /n:"test1" /a:"test1" /host:192.168.1.110 /pass:test /t:title message` would work after that to send messages.

For anything else, you can probably refer to the docs and hack together something to fill in the message content.

Tested between two windows 10 systems and it works for me.

If you want to send messages from *linux* to a GFW or growl for mac instance, you can use [gntp-send](https://superuser.com/questions/471590/how-do-i-use-gntp-send)

Comment: I'd forgotten about Growl - I remember playing with it about 10 years ago when I got my original Windows Home Server. Don't think I ever managed to get it to work reliably - I'll have to have another look

Comment: I'll edit my answer in a bit. I'm away from any sort of PC till this evening but I have a working instance set up with exactly what you need.

Comment: Subsequently discovered [Pushover](https://pushover.net/) notifications (which I'm already using) can received on the desktop now, so I'm using that for now to keep things simpler ([see my answer](http://superuser.com/a/1180705/219838)), but I may start using Growl for any notifications that don't need to get on my phone