# Triggering the Windows Notification Center?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, notifications, notification-area

How can I create a desktop shortcut to trigger the Windows notification center (the right notification panel)? I believe I have Windows 11 Pro.

If not, is there a batch command for opening up the Windows Notification Center?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send a notification to a Windows 10 computer from the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1179758/how-can-i-send-a-notification-to-a-windows-10-computer-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

[Per Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-open-notification-center-and-quick-settings-f8dc196e-82db-5d67-f55e-ba5586fbb038) to open Action Center, do any of the following:

- On the right end of the taskbar, select the Action Center  icon.
- Press the Windows logo key  + A.
- On a touchscreen device, swipe in from the right edge of the screen.

If you're absolutely set on opening it from a desktop shortcut, you can also install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), save the following as a .ahk file, and copy it to your desktop:

```
Send #a
Exit
```

This script simply sends the above-mentioned keyboard shortcut, <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> any time it's clicked.

Comment: Thank you for the useful reply.  Is there a way to accomplish this without AutoHotkey?

Comment: @TomNg. There's no good to send a ⊞ Win keypress without essentially writing your own program to do so. There is a SendKeys VBA method that can be called from a Batch file, but it lacks the ability to send the Windows key specifically.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. Appreciate your time.